# How to convert a GUID to a string in C#?

Tags: c#, string, guid

I'm new to C#.

I know in vb.net, i can do this:

```
Dim guid as string = System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString
```

In C#, I'm trying to do

```
String guid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString;
```

but i get an "**Cannot convert method group 'ToString' to non-delegate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method**?" error.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You're missing the `()` after `ToString` that marks it as a function call vs. a function reference (the kind you pass to delegates), which incidentally is why c# has no `AddressOf` operator, it's implied by how you type it.

Try this:

```
string guid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Answer (score 148):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4.aspx) the method `Guid.ToString(string format)` returns a string representation of the value of this Guid instance, according to the provided format specifier.

Examples:

- `guidVal.ToString()` or `guidVal.ToString("D")` returns 32 hex digits
  separated by hyphens: `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`
- `guidVal.ToString("N")` returns 32 hex digits:`00000000000000000000000000000000`
- `guidVal.ToString("B")` returns 32 hex digits separated by hyphens, enclosed in braces:`{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`
- `guidVal.ToString("P")` returns 32 hex digits separated by hyphens, enclosed in parentheses: `(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000)`

Answer (score 28):

Here are examples of output from each of the format specifiers:

```
N: cd26ccf675d64521884f1693c62ed303
D: cd26ccf6-75d6-4521-884f-1693c62ed303
B: {cd26ccf6-75d6-4521-884f-1693c62ed303}
P: (cd26ccf6-75d6-4521-884f-1693c62ed303)
X: {0xcd26ccf6,0x75d6,0x4521,{0x88,0x4f,0x16,0x93,0xc6,0x2e,0xd3,0x03}}
```

The default is `D`.

[Run this yourself](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQFEAeAHJzkCWA9gHYBqUCBUwANigDQwgJwkA+AAgAwAEnARgDcAWABQnAMz8BANn4AmGQHZeAb3G8t/aYPmcALLwCyUAiQAUASk3aNY7Y94A3SrwDmcAgBNeAXl4AcS9vADoAOQgAd2Cfa1EHJy1BAE4LABIAInCQdU8fEHCAX0yrBKTkgTSsgBFctXzvEBqSstsk1IzMgCF6xpBu1vKKzqyABT6QkDGh9qdRzIANSYLF2cStIvEioA=).

Answer (score 9):

Did you write

```
String guid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString;
```

or

```
String guid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

notice the parenthesis.

Answer (score 9):

In Visual Basic, you can call a parameterless method without the braces (`()`). In C#, they're mandatory. So you should write:

```
String guid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Without the braces, you're assigning the method itself (instead of its result) to the variable `guid`, and obviously the method cannot be converted to a `String`, hence the error.

Answer (score 7):

You need

```
String guid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
String guid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Otherwise it's a delegate.

Answer (score 5):

you are missing () on the end of ToString.

Answer (score 4):

```
Guid guidId = Guid.Parse("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx");
string guidValue = guidId.ToString("D"); //return with hyphens
```

Answer (score 2):

Following Sonar rules, you should whenever you can try to protect yourself, and use 
`System.globalisation` whenever it's possible like for `DateTime.ToString()`.

So regarding the other answers you could use:

```
guid.ToString("", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

where `""` can be replaces by : N, D, B , P and X for more infos see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55131642/9240942).

Example [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQFEAeAHJzkCWA9gHYBqUCBUwANigDQwgJwkA+AAgEwCMAsAChOABgAEnXgDoA4rSLAotAgC9YxEgG4hQngGYxAbyFjTE7txNnjgs3bEA3SmIDmcAgBMxAXjEz3HlIAchAA7v6eABQAlNq29qaSAJyRACQAREEgRm6eIEEAvumxVgnJaekAItmGuR4glUUl8WW8KRkAQjV1IB1NcQmJbRUACt0BICP9pfblGQAa43nz0y32M3bldVIAKkQAyjBUJC6R6ekMYgDCcLTwSACSJGBEUk9OVFAkMDd3iBDRZp2ApCApAA)