# How to extract Guid from file name?

Tags: c#, regex, guid

I want to extract Guid from this below string array and want output like this:

```
Output:Log.txt,Logging.txt

string[] str = new string[] { "1250a2d5-cd40-4bcc-a979-9d6f2cd62b9fLog.txt", "bdb31966-e3c4-4344-b02c-305c0eb0fa0aLogging.txt" }; //file name are Log.txt and Logging.txt
List<string> list= new List<string>();
foreach (var item in str)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
    {
        list.Add();  // here i want to store Log.txt and Logging.txt
    }
}
```

How to do this??

Comment: `list.Add("Log.txt")` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = new string[] { "1250a2d5-cd40-4bcc-a979-9d6f2cd62b9fLog.txt", "bdb31966-e3c4-4344-b02c-305c0eb0fa0aLogging.txt" }; //file name are Log.txt and Logging.txt

var arr = str.Select(s=>s.Substring(36)).Where(s=>s.Any()).ToArray();
```

You can see it in action here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eHy6Fo

Comment: so are you sure about it that guid are of 36 digits only??

Comment: GUIDs are 128 bits, or 32 characters in hex. In that particular representation there's 4 extra dashes -- makes 36!

Comment: Thanks for the info and the solution.Can i know the reason for downvote?

Comment: On your post? Probably because it's not very clearly and professionally stated.

Comment: Ok.What about this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700361/how-to-convert-a-guid-to-a-string-in-c/1700370#1700370.Is this question very professionally stated?

Comment: Can you help me with this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407205/how-to-remove-guid-from-file-name-when-creating-zip-file

Comment: I have updated my question now check:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407205/how-to-remove-guid-from-file-name-when-creating-zip-file#33407305