# How to remove guid from file name when creating zip file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, zip, dotnetzip

When user uploads multiple documents I am storing their files in my project like this:

```
 Guid id;
 id = Guid.NewGuid();
 string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../Uploads"),
 Path.GetFileName(id + item.FileName));
 item.SaveAs(filePath);
```

So files are saved like this in my project:

1. 1250a2d5-cd40-4bcc-a979-9d6f2cd62b9fLog.txt
2. bdb31966-e3c4-4344-b02c-305c0eb0fa0aLogging.txt

Now when creating zip files I am getting same name of this files when extracting zip files but I don't want guid in my file name after user downloads file.

However I have tried to remove guid from my file name but getting error `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`.

This is my code:

```
using (var zip = new ZipFile())
{
    var str = new string[] { "1250a2d5-cd40-4bcc-a979-9d6f2cd62b9fLog.txt", "bdb31966-e3c4-4344-b02c-305c0eb0fa0aLogging.txt" }; //file name are Log.txt and Logging.txt
    string[] str1 = str .Split(',');
    foreach (var item in str1)
    {
        string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + item.Substring(36));//as guid are of 36 digits
        zip.AddFile(filePath, "files");
    }
    zip.Save(memoryStream);//Getting error here
}
```

Comment: Does the file defined by filePath exists at server mapped folder?

Comment: @user1672994:see Kevin Answer.He has the point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZipFile is throwing an exception because it can't find the file on disk as you have given it a name of a file that does not exist (by doing a .Substring()). To make it work you would have to rename the file using File.Copy with your new file name and then give that same file name to Zip.AddFile().

```
  var orgFileName = "1250a2d5-cd40-4bcc-a979-9d6f2cd62b9fLog.txt";
  var newFileName = orgFileName.Substring (36);
  File.Copy (orgFileName, newFileName, true);
  zip.AddFile (newFileName);
```

Comment: Yes you are right i think but would be more better if you can post code of what you are saying

Comment: You don't need to. Thats up to you.

Comment: yes i need to because i am getting same error with your code on zip.save but i have solved it because now i am removing file after zip.save

Comment: That may be because you trying to create a zip the second time and the copy operation is failing. I have changed File.Copy to overwrite existing files so that it no longer throws an exception.

Comment: ok now i have done the same as you have told and add true option and now i am not getting that error.Could you please explain how?

Comment: File.Copy by default will throw an exception if a file with the same name you trying to copy to already exists. When not using File.Delete after zipping that file will still be there for the next time you try and zip the same file. Adding "true" to File.Copy overwrites any existing files.

Comment: Nope sorry to say but this is not working.i havent put file.delete so but as i have now added file.delete before zip.save it is throwing error.

Comment: I have removed File.Delete as that is confusing things. You can't delete the file before calling zip.save.

Comment: please check my asnwer

Answer (score 1):

You should use archive and ArchiveEntry. The rough code snipets how to do it (i don't test it):

```
    using(var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true)) {
        {
            //using(var zip = new ZipFile()) {
            var str = new string[] { "1250a2d5-cd40-4bcc-a979-9d6f2cd62b9fLog.txt", "bdb31966-e3c4-4344-b02c-305c0eb0fa0aLogging.txt" }; //file name are Log.txt and Logging.txt
                                                                                                                                         //string[] str = str.Split(',');
            foreach(var item in str) {
                using(var entryStream = archive.CreateEntry("files/" + item.Substring(36)).Open()) {
                    string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + item);
                    var content = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
                    entryStream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

sample for using DotNetZip:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
var str = new string[] { "1250a2d5-cd40-4bcc-a979-9d6f2cd62b9fLog.txt", "bdb31966-e3c4-4344-b02c-305c0eb0fa0aLogging.txt" };
            foreach(var item in str) {
                    string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + item);
                    var content = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
                    ZipEntry e = zip.AddEntry("files/" + item.Substring(36), content);
                }
            }  
zip.Save(memoryStream);
}
```

Comment: sorry to say but i want to use Dotnetzip only so i would be really thankfull if you can suggest some improvement in my answer only

Answer (score 0):

Taking source from @kevin answer i have manage to solve this:

```
    List<string> newfilename1 = new List<string>();
        using (var zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            var str = new string[] { "1250a2d5-cd40-4bcc-a979-9d6f2cd62b9fLog.txt", "bdb31966-e3c4-4344-b02c-305c0eb0fa0aLogging.txt" }; //file name are Log.txt and Logging.txt
            string[] str1 = str .Split(',');
            foreach (var item in str1)
            {
                  string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + item);
                            string newFileName = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + item.Substring(36));
                            newfilename1.Add(newFileName);
                            System.IO.File.Copy(filePath,newFileName);
                            zip.AddFile(newFileName,"");
            }
            zip.Save(memoryStream);
 foreach (var item in newfilename1)
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(item);
                    }
        }
```